# Possible to create my own OSM XML file? If so, how to use the < relation > tag?

Tags: xml, openstreetmap

As you may know, OpenStreetMap (OSM) datasets are publicly available, but only contain randomly marked nodes/coordinates uploaded by volunteers. I have a clean city-level dataset with nodes and ways (for example, on "Main Street", there are several coordinates within a road section), and I would like to build my own OSM XML file for a research project. Is it possible?

Before asking the question, I found this link (http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OSM_XML) and made an OSM XML file with only the tags of `< node >` and `< way >`. But, when I call `osrm-extract`, I get the XML parsing error, which throws an instance of `osmium::xml_error`. If it is caused by not having `< relation >`, in which case do I need to use this tag? How to build the relations for my self-built OSM XML file?

Thank you for your answers in advance :-)

Comment: Could you share your XML test file ? Also, according to https://github.com/osmcode/libosmium/blob/master/include/osmium/io/detail/xml_input_format.hpp#L72 , a more complete error could be output, which would point to the error

Comment: Thank you for your answer, @Eric. Please find a sample xml file enclosed: [link](https://github.com/gchen55/OSM/blob/master/map.osm)

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with relations in the first place. Your nodes look strange and need to be fixed. The correct attribute names are lat/**lon** and not lat/**lng** as in your example. With this change in place, I'm able to open your file in JOSM (Java OpenStreetMap Editor).

BTW: my OSRM version triggers another error with your example file: `called after throwing an instance of 'osmium::invalid_location'` - clearly pointing to the wrong OSM XML file format. Not sure why you're getting a different error message, though.

Example:

Before (incorrect)

```
lat="37.7976165" lng="-122.4512781"
```

After (corrected)

```
lat="37.7976165" lon="-122.4512781"
```

Please remember to *not* upload this data to OpenStreetMap due to possible issues concerning copyright and mechanical edit policy!

Comment: Whoops! Thank you for pointing out the error. The dataset won't be shared publicly:-)

Answer (score 1):

When ran through `osmium check-refs`, some errors are found :

```
Found a node after a way.
This command expects the input file to be ordered: First nodes in order of ID,
then ways in order of ID, then relations in order of ID.

Node IDs out of order.
This command expects the input file to be ordered: First nodes in order of ID,
then ways in order of ID, then relations in order of ID.
```

Through `osmium show` :

```
lon/lat:   214.7483647,214.7483647 INVALID LOCATION!
```

As pointed by mmd, lat/**lon** should be used instead of lat/**lng**.

Comment: Thank you for your answers, and also the tool you mention:-)